# DFS algorithm not finding any solution to Peg Solitaire game

Tags: python, algorithm, search, depth-first-search

I am trying to implement a Depth-First Search algorithm to find a solution to a Peg Solitaire game. However, the program appears to run in an infinite loop and I am not sure what causes this problem. According to [Depth-first search solves Peg Solitaire](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2840090_Depth-first_search_solves_Peg_Solitaire), the first solution should be found after visiting 20 278 nodes. This is my implementation:

dfs.py

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, board, parent, move) -> None:
        self.board = board
        self.parent = parent
        self.move = move

class StackFrontier:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.frontier = []

    def push(self, node):
        self.frontier.append(node)

    def pop(self):
        return self.frontier.pop(-1)
    
    def empty(self):
        return len(self.frontier) == 0
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.frontier)
```

pegsolitaire.py

```
import copy
from dfs import *
from termcolor import colored

O = "O"
X = "X"

initial_board = [
        [" ", " ", O, O ,O, " ", " "],
        [" ", " ", O, O ,O, " ", " "],
            [O, O, O, O, O, O, O],
            [O, O, O, X, O, O, O],
            [O, O, O, O, O, O, O],
        [" ", " ", O, O ,O, " ", " "],
        [" ", " ", O, O ,O, " ", " "]
    ]

frontier = StackFrontier()
branches_visited = 0
visited_branches = set()

def winner(board):
    count = 0
                
    for row in board:
        count += row.count(O)
        if count > 1:
            return False
    
    return True

def moves(board):
    moves = []

    for i in range(7):
        for j in range(7):
            if board[i][j] == X:
                if i + 2 < 7 and board[i + 2][j] == O and board[i + 1][j] == O:
                    move = [[i + 2, j], [i + 1, j], [i, j]]
                    moves.append(move)
                if i - 2 >= 0 and board[i - 2][j] == O and board[i - 1][j] == O:
                    move = [[i - 2, j], [i - 1, j], [i, j]]
                    moves.append(move)
                if j + 2 < 7 and board[i][j + 2] == O and board[i][j + 1] == O:
                    move = [[i, j + 2], [i, j + 1], [i, j]]
                    moves.append(move)
                if j - 2 >= 0 and board[i][j - 2] == O and board[i][j - 1] == O:
                    move = [[i, j - 2], [i, j - 1], [i, j]]
                    moves.append(move)

    print("Possible moves:")
    print(moves)
    print()

    return moves

def result(board, move):
    board_copy = copy.deepcopy(board)

    from_coords = move[0]
    over_coords = move[1]
    to_coords = move[2]

    board_copy[from_coords[0]][from_coords[1]] = X
    board_copy[over_coords[0]][over_coords[1]] = X
    board_copy[to_coords[0]][to_coords[1]] = O

    print(f"Result of move {move}:")
    print()
    for i in range(7):
        for j in range(7):
            if [i, j] == from_coords:
                print(colored(board_copy[i][j], "green"), end=" ")
            elif [i, j] == over_coords:
                print(colored(board_copy[i][j], "green"), end=" ")
            elif [i, j] == to_coords:
                print(colored(board_copy[i][j], "green"), end=" ")
            else:
                print(board_copy[i][j], end=" ")
        
        print()
    
    print()

    return board_copy


def solve(board):
    initial_state = Node(board, None, None)
    frontier.push(initial_state)

    while not frontier.empty():
        global branches_visited
        print("---------- NEXT ----------")
        print(f"Branches visited: {branches_visited}.")
        branches_visited += 1

        currentNode = frontier.pop()

        print("Current board:")
        print()
        for i in range(7):
            for j in range(7):
                print(currentNode.board[i][j], end=" ")

            print()

        print()

        if winner(currentNode.board):
            solution = []

            while currentNode.parent != None:
                solution.append(currentNode)
                currentNode = currentNode.parent

            solution.reverse()
            return solution
        
        for move in moves(currentNode.board):
            next = Node(result(currentNode.board, move), currentNode, move)

            if next not in visited_branches:
                frontier.push(next)
                visited_branches.add(next)
                print(f"Board added to the frontier. Current frontier size: {len(frontier)}\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(solve(initial_board))
```

- The *winner* function checks if there is only one peg left on the board. If True the solution has been found.
- The *moves* function returns a list of all possible moves in the board. A move is a list of board coordinates of the peg that is being moved - [from, over, to]
- The *result* function creates a copy of the board, performs the given move and returns the board that results.

I left the program running for hours and no solution has been found. I appreciate any hints towards the solution of my problem.

Comment: *"I left the program running for hours and no solution has been found."* <<< My advice: don't let a program run for hours with no output unless you're confident that it works. Add some print statements (print to a text file, not to the console). Make it print the moves and board states that it's exploring, so that you can see where it gets stuck.